# Why does jBPM fail to connect to Guvnor?

Tags: tomcat, jbpm, drools-guvnor

I followed the steps in this https://community.jboss.org/message/715223, to get jBPM designer in Tomcat 6. However, as soon as i try to create a new BPMN2 process and give it a name like 'Test10', the canvas opens up, but i get this error in Tomcat :-

```
INFO  12-12 11:18:22,328 (LoggingHelper.java:info:49)    USER:guest CREATING new asset name [Test10] in package [defaultPackage] (null: -1, -1): Premature end of file.[12/12/13 11:18:25:025 IST] ERROR impl.JbpmPreprocessingUnit: Connection refused: connect Setting up default workitem configuration End setting up default workitem configuration [12/12/13 1:18:30:030 IST] ERROR impl.UUIDBasedJbpmRepository: Unable to connect to Gunvor. Is it running? [Connection refused: connect]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check configuration of drools. 
first check jbpm.profile in designer war. 
find  "externalloadurl protocol=" tag and see if it is pointing to correct guvnor with user/password.